# Create a method that Concatenate Contacts Names from a List<Contact>

Tags: apex, list

I'm testing my code, but it is not going within the for loop, does anyone have any suggestions?

```
    global static String concatenateNames(List<Contact> contacts, String separator)
{
    List<Contact> contactsToConcatenate = [SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contacts];
    String result;
    Integer counter = 0;
    for(Contact c : contacts)
    {
        if(counter < contacts.size())
        {
            result = String.join(contactsToConcatenate, separator);
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            result = String.join(contactsToConcatenate, '.');
        }
    }
    System.debug(result);
    return result;
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Please check your List<Contact> contacts & contacts.size() value in before the loop via debug log. If it's empty, your for loop condition will fail and it's doesn't execute the inside "if" condition I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list of Contacts passed in have had their Name fields queried already, then this code would do the job:

```
global static String concatenateNames(List<Contact> contacts, String separator) {

    String[] names = new String[] {};
    for (Contact c : contacts) {
        names.add(c.Name);
    }

    // If the Contact records passed in are already in a good order remove this
    names.sort();

    return String.join(names, separator);
}
```